# I can't set a .svg file as a maui app icon

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

I can't set my .svg file as my app icon. I put the .svg file inside the Resources folder and changed its "Build Actions" properties to MauiIcon and in the .csproj file I wrote:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YDAo.png

Comment: typo `splashh.svg` instead of `splash.svg` the double `h` ?

Comment: no, the file name is correct :(

Comment: Please don't show image of your code , put it in your question .

Comment: Did you rebuild the project after change the .svg

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I suspect Maui creates `.png` files per platform, from that `.svg`. Try `Resources\cciconn.png`. Or just `cciconn.png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps

1. Make it a basic svg file , you can take a png file and use tool to convert it to svg file .
2. Call the file the same as the default so `appicon.svg`, edit in your `.csproj`

   ```
   <MauiIcon Include="Resources\appicon.svg" />
   ```

Refer to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3755#issuecomment-1063138958 .